# How do I retrieve the object_id of a facebook apprequest?

Tags: facebook, apprequests

In our app, we send AppRequests with "action_type"="send" and "object_id"=. The object_id is reflected in the apprequest UI, so we're doing that correctly. But when we retrieve them on the recipient side with a GET to /me/apprequests there is no action_type or object_id (or anything related to object). If we add ?fields=object,object_id,action_type we get action_type=send but still nothing about the object.

So are OpenGraph objects only useful for slightly modifying the end-user UI of apprequests? In other words, object_id determine "what" virtual thing is sent but that information is available only when sending and to the end-user, not the app.

Comment: It seems I can just put a string into the 'data' field. So for now I'll put the same text into object_id and into data, which is less than ideal.